# Who is Shiki talking to in one of his dreams in one of the Far Side Routes

Tags: tsukihime

In one of the Far Side of the Moon Routes (I think Hisui's Route), when he falls asleep he has a "Dream". In it him (or SHIKI) encounter another serial killer who after the 2 have a drink together decides to leave the city believing that there would be trouble if the city had 2 serial killers.

I'm wondering who this other person was and if they too was sent by the same person who sent Nrvnqsr Chaos to kill Arcueid Brunestud (I remember reading about it the other day but I can't remember who, and I definitely know it wasn't Roa)

Comment: If you don't find an answer here, you could try at anime.SE, VNs are on topic there, too.